# How to iterate with javascript a json response from symfony2

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, symfony

i want to itarate a json response from symfony and put it in a table td>

my action :

```
    $search = $this->getDoctrine->...;
    $serializer = $this->get('serializer');

    foreach ($search as $key => $value) {

        $search[$key] = $serializer->serialize($value, "json");
    }

    $reponse = new JsonResponse($search);

    return $reponse;
```

this is what i have in my twig ( i examine it with Firebug ):

[image]

i have a  to display at least something but sometimes i have undefined or nothing ... this my javascript function

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var dataString = $("form").serialize();
  var typerequest = $("form").find('input[name="typerequest"]').val();
  $('#filtreperseance').ajaxForm({
     type: "POST",
     url: Routing.generate('myroute'),
     data: dataString,
     success: function (response) {

       $.each(response, function (cle, valeur) {
           $("#test").html(valeur);
       });                   

     }
  });
});
```

EDIT 1 : Console.log

[image]

EDIT 2 :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have done a mistake when i returned the JSOn from Controller . its Ok now

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to cut down the problem. First make sure, the JSON is valid and looks the way you expect. Don't use jQuery at this point. Call the symfony controller in your browser directly. Then check the json. http://jsonviewer.stack.hu might be of use.

Once you verfified that the JSON itself is valid and contains what you need, we can look at the jQuery part. Then we'd need the code and the errors you get.

Comment: Okay. Then I'd add a

     $.each(response, function (cle, valeur) {
           console.log(valeur);
       });

The console log will give you a nice output in the browser dev tools for debugging. You said sometimes you'd get nothing or something is missing? What exactly is missing at what variable is empty?

Comment: i added a pic for you after writing the last code of console.log

Comment: Okay. Looks to me that this adresse hamma damo string is not what you wnated to get. Or am I wrong? You wrote you want to put it in a table TD... Can you be more precise? What should your outcome look like?

Comment: i want to display like the picture EDIT2

Comment: Okay, and what is "undefined or missing" as you wrote?

Comment: because before i wrote this issue i have done a for() when i put in it $('#test').html(response[i].id); to display the id of candidates so i have undefined undefined.